# ens33:1 is not activ at startup

Tags: debian, network-interface

I setup my network (/etc/network/interfaces) as below on debian 10 with ens33 (VM):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address A.B.C.D
netmask E.F.G.H
hwaddress ether 00:**:**:**:**:**

auto ens33:1
iface ens33:1 inet static
address I.J.K.L
netmask M.N.O.P
```

ens33 is up and answer (ping OK), but ens33:1 is not up.

My question is why the ens33:1 interface is not up after the boot (unlike ens33) ?
Do I forget anything ?

Comment: Add the output of `ip addr` after reboot to the question